# Retrieve object from a Java Swing component

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on a Java Swing project where I need to retrieve the object/instance that created a panel in order to call a simple save method particular to that instance.

You have a JFrame with a JTabbedPane that has tabs created by instancing a class which builds a JPanel and adds it to the JTabbedPane, I need to find the specific instance from the selected JPanel/tab on the JTabbedPane to then call it's save method.

Any ideas?
Thanks for your time!

```
public class frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 Builds a frame dubbed "frame" that is static.
 Builds a static JTabbedPane dubbed "pane"and adds it to the frame.
 Creates a button that creates a new instance of sheet.

 public void actionPerformed(MAGIC!){
  See if a button on the panel has been pressed and uses the currently selected tab to locate the correct instance of sheet to run it's save method.
 }
}

public class sheet extends JPanel{
 In constructor makes a JPanel and adds it to "pane"

 Describes a save method that outputs a variable unique to the instance.
}
```

Comment: I think that for the best specific help, you'll need to tell us more of the details of your current code. Are you using code-generation software to create the GUI such as the NetBean's gui creator?

Comment: No, I'm doing by hand as to better learn about Java and Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out all I needed to do was store new tab objects in an ArrayList *derp*. Thanks for your attempts though guys!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Ooh, before that though, I need to say that the problem was caused by misuse of class extensions. When you extend a class it itself becomes the object you've extended which means you can -in my case- run the save command from it. Just remember the 'this' keyword when referring to the class itself!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field in the new JPanels that point to the instance of the creator. I don't think there is any such method to point back to parent class in the API.

--EDIT--
You may want to check 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
getSelectedIndex() may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but how would I go about this? I've never used pointers directly, let alone in a language that doesn't have pointers in the typical sense. ><

Ty for the reply though!

Comment: @user1305495: He means to simply to give your GUI class a variable that holds a reference to its creator, that's all.

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea, I'll update the question with some pseudo code to further elaborate as explaining in any other way gives me a bit of a headache...

Comment: Dear Edit,
I'm afraid the getSelectedComponent/index returns the panel. The entire point of this question was to see if I could get the object from that panel :/
Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just connecting back to the original creator, my approach to this was to create / use an interface that expicitly supports saving. I created something for this in TUS, my sourceforge project

http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/io/filepersist/

Check out Persistable and Persistable2. Of course anything can be a Persistable, but the abstraction let's you get away from explicit ties back to the creator class

Comment: I might give this a try, however I'm afraid I'm not the most skilled with interfaces ><